# Yammer API to get multiple pages of recent results

Tags: java, api, apache-httpclient-4.x, yammer

I'm using yammer API to extract this month of yammer messages.

The exact same request sometimes return messages and sometimes not. In both cases the response code is `200 OK` so I shouldn't be hitting the rate limiter which is [documented to 429](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits).

How can I continue troubleshooting?

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?older_than=12345
```

Response status: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK [code: 200]`
Response body: (that time when the request does NOT return messages)

```
{
  "threaded_extended": {},
  "messages": [],
  "references": [],
  "external_references": [],
  "meta": {
    "older_available": false,
    "requested_poll_interval": 60,
    "realtime": {
      "uri": "https://1-148945-4310388-731.rt.yammer.com/cometd/",
      "authentication_token": "...",
      "channel_id": "..."
    },
    "last_seen_message_id": null,
    "current_user_id": 123456,
    "followed_references": [],
    "ymodules": [],
    "newest_message_details": null,
    "feed_name": "Company Feed",
    "feed_desc": "Company public messages",
    "direct_from_body": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround has been to retry requests that resulted in 0 messages. I'm guessing this is either a flaw in the API or that I'm using it in a way not intended (i.e. querying it more frequently than allowed).